# Simulating modem slows down WCF calls unrealistically

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I'm developing some WCF web service calls, and want to test how the download times compare when using a modem connection.

I started Fiddler and checked the Rules -> Performance -> Simulate Modem speeds option. I can see that this works, as if I refresh a web page, it's slower. I tried downloading some files of around 3-6Mb, and again I could see the difference. Normally these would be pretty instant, with the performance option on, they took a few seconds.

I then tried to make my service calls. Without the Fiddler option, they typically take about 300-400ms to download about 1.5Mb. However, with the performance option on, the call takes about **40-60 seconds**. This is way to slow to be realistic.

This is all running on my local machine, using Visual Studio 2015.

Anyone any idea why it's so slow?

Comment: It looks like [by default](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/PerfTesting) "Simulate Modem Speeds" goes to 1kb/150ms = 6.66kilobytes per second. (1.5 megabytes)*(1024 kilobytes/megabyte)/(6.66 kilobytes/second) = 3.8 minutes, but if I'm understanding correctly this doesn't account for the actual download e.g., you download 1kb, then it sleeps 150ms, so really it's like 155ms per kilobyte or whatever, so it should be even longer than 3.8 minutes. 60 seconds is 4x faster than it should be going, no?

Comment: @Quantic Dunno, all seems odd to me. I would have thought that simulating modem speeds would just slow down the download, not introduce pauses. I tried reducing the delays as shown in this blog post http://www.rightmove.co.uk/dev/blog/testing-slow-connection-speeds-with-fiddler/, but it was still painfully slow.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "slow"? A modem maxes out at 53.3 kilobits per second which is 6.66 kilobytes/sec and matches up with their value well. This translates to 400 kilobytes per minute, so it takes 10 minutes to download ~4mb. This isn't "slow" for a modem, this is as fast as any modem can ever go, so I feel like the answer so your question "why is it so slow?" is: It's not slow, it's actually going the right speed for a modem, even a bit faster. As for simulating speeds I don't know a "correct" way to do it, just that fiddler appears to sleep every 1kb to simulate slower speeds.

Comment: @Quantic What I meant was then when downloading a file using my web browser, I got 3Mb in a few seconds, whereas when accessing my WCF service from code, it took 40-60 seconds to download 1.5Mb. Without the modem simulation, the WCF call completed in about 500ms.

Comment: Ok so if anything it's going *too fast*, not too slow. 1.5 megabytes should take 4 minutes to download on a modem, not 60 seconds. Or it's going about the right speed if it's 1.5 megabits which is only ~188 kilobytes. A modem goes about 6 kilobytes per second = 48 kilobits per second, in 60 seconds it will have downloaded only 360 kilobytes ~= 2.8 megabits. Modems are *slow*, very slow relative to today's data.

Comment: @quantic Hmm, guess you're right. Seems odd that there's such a discrepancy between the download time in the browser and from the code. Should be comparable

Answer (score 1):

**Simulate Modem Speeds** is a really hacky feature that doesn't work very well, especially if the upstream network itself is not extremely fast.

For better emulation that works correctly across parallel requests, please run [WinShaper](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/win-shaper) in parallel with Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, it looks like exactly what I need. I'll try it out next week, and hopefully mark this as an answer!